# Efficient segment boundary marking after segmentation of an image

Tags: matlab, boundary, image-segmentation, morphological-analysis

One can mark the boundary of a binary image by *bwboundaries* function of MATLAB.

What should be done for obtaining boundaries of all segments as a binary image?

I have segmented an image and want to know if there is a way to mark boundaries between each neighbouring segment without applying morphological operations on each segment.

I have added images to illustrate what i want to do. Actually i want to obtain a binary image that keeps pink boundary marker pixels between all segments. Thus, I can overlay them with original image by the help of [imoverlay](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502-image-overlay) function of Steve Eddins.

Random colored labeling of segmentation result:

[image]

Roughly-marked pink boundaries between segments:

[image]

Comment: can you give a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the region boundaries using a range filter, which finds the intensity range within each pixel's neighborhood.  This takes advantage of the fact that the label matrix only has non-zero range at the region boundaries.

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPiA3.png');
boundaries = rangefilt(im,ones(3)) > 0;
imoverlay(label2rgb(im),boundaries,[0 0 0]);
```

These edges are also two pixels wide. Actually, I think the edges have to be two pixels wide; otherwise the regions will "lose" pixels to the border non-uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is a nice catch about the situation, you're right. I realized your solution is slightly faster than the solution proposed with erosion-dilation formerly.

Answer (score 3):

Since erosion and dilation work on non-binary images as well, you can write

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPiA3.png');
ei = imerode(img,ones(3));
di = imdilate(img,ones(3));
boundaries = ei~=img | di~=img;
```

This results in a bw image that has a boundary at the edge of each colored region (thus, the boundary line will be two pixels wide).

[image]

Note that this will not return an ordered list of pixels as `bwboundaries`, but rather a logical mask like `bwperim`, which is what `imoverlay` needs as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed the first fact you mentioned about erosion dilation. That helps a lot.

Comment: @Gulcan: If you're concerned about speed, you may want to use `strel` instead of `ones` for the mask, i.e. `strel('square',3)` instead of `ones(3)`. This will use a separable filter that is faster.

Answer (score 1):

As a round-about way, I thought of making use of *edge* function of MATLAB. 
First, I need to apply something like a *label2gray* operation. *labels* is the segmentation output (first image provided in the question) in the code below.

```
grayLabels = mat2gray(255* double(labels) ./ double(max(labels(:)))); %label2gray
bw_boundaries = edge(grayLabels,0.001);
```

Comment: For this approach, just normalize the label matrix: `nim = im - min(im(:)); nim = nim/max(nim(:));`. Nearly all of MATLAB's image processing functions work on normalized matrices of type double.

Comment: Secondly, in this case the gradient methods don't find all the edge pixels. Display the overlay and take an up-close look at the region corners.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that :) i need to adjust 0.001 hard threshold according to max number assigned in labeled image.